# DIY Laser cutter for small Acrylic robot baseplate

Tags: laser

Need help to choose **desk top, low cost, DIY/High school grade laser cutter** for making base plate for DIY robots, about maximum A4 paper size, as this photo.  Idea, comment, advises, even if only partially cover some and not all questions, are welcome.

[image]

1. What power is needed to cut Acrylic 3 to 5mm thick. Many sellers at 40 to 60 watts range. What can these do?
2. How cut thickness depends on cut speed? To what extend can I choose slow speed to cut thicker sheet.
3. Does cut thickness depends on color/clear acrylic? It is CO2 laser.
4. Some units have options, like air blower and honeycomb bottom plate. What are their functions? what options are useful for this case.
5. Which CAD 2D drawing software is best supported by these range of products?
6. Apart from main function of cutting flat acrylic plate, some has additional Z axis motor to rise/lower work piece for engrave/photo/line_letter marking on 3D objects. What software is needed to support these 3D operation.